# JMeter - Run a python script before calling each HTTP request sampler

Tags: python, jmeter, javabeans, beanshell

I am new to Jmeter. My HTTP request sampler call looks like this

```
Path= /image/**image_id**/list/
Header =  "Key" : "Key_Value"
```

Key value is generated by calling a python script which uses the `image_id` to generate a unique key.

Before each sampler I wanted to generate the key using python script which will be passed as a header to the next HTTP Request sampler.

I know I have to used some kind of preprocessor to do that. Can anyone help me do it using a preprocessor in jmeter.

Comment: A simpler approach I tend to use is to run use the script beforehand to create a file with parameters that is read via the JMeter CSV handler resulting in a `${imgid}` variable in your sampler URL.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) is what you're looking for.

Example Beanshell code will look as follows:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = r.exec("/usr/bin/python /path/to/your/script.py");
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(line);

}

b.close();
vars.put("ID",response.toString());
```

The code above will execute Python script and put it's response into `ID` variable.

You will be able to refer it in your HTTP Request as 
    /image/${ID}/list/

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in Apache JMeter and a kind of Beanshell cookbook.

You can also put your request under [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) to exclude PreProcessor execution time from load report.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Can you also let me know how to pass parameter to this python file

Comment: You can just add arguments after script like `/usr/bin/python /path/to/your/script.py param1 param2`

Comment: I am passing parameter like this it is not working     String s ="param"    /usr/bin/python /path/to/your/script.py s . In python script it is printed as "s" and not "param"

Comment: `String s = "param"; Process p = r.exec("/usr/bin/python /path/to/your/script.py " + s);` - this way it should work

Comment: If you're going to fork a process, why wouldn't you use the OS Process Sampler?

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution posted by **Eugene Kazakov** [here](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/Using-Python-or-Ruby-from-Jmeter-td5716088.html):

> JSR223 sampler has good possibility to write and execute some code,
>   just  put jython.jar into /lib directory, choose in "Language" pop-up
>   menu jython  and write your code in this sampler.

[Sadly there is a bug in Jython, but there are some suggestion on the page.](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47511)

[More here.](https://www.google.com/search?q=jython%20jmeter)

Comment: i would not recomand jython library as its very bugy, it worked fine for me with low number of threads, but when running a load test with many threads it just kept getting deadlocks and crashed my tests

Answer (score 2):

You can use a BSF PreProcessor.

First download the [Jython Library](http://www.jython.org/downloads.html) and save to your jmeter's lib directory.

On your HTTP sampler add a BSF PreProcessor, choose as language Jython and perform your needed magic to obtain the id, as an example I used this one:

```
import random
randImageString = ""
for i in range(16):
    randImageString = randImageString + chr(random.randint(ord('A'),ord('Z')))

vars.put("randimage", randImageString)
```

Note the `vars.put("randimage",randImageString")` which will insert the variable available later to jmeter.

Now on your test you can use `${randimage}` when you need it:

[image: HTTP Sampler with parameters]

Now every Request will be different changing with the value put to randimage on the Python Script.

Comment: i would not recomand jython library as its very bugy, it worked fine for me with low number of threads, but when running a load test with many threads it just kept getting deadlocks and crashed my tests