# How to make async http request from jmeter while changing path dynamically before each call

Tags: asynchronous, jmeter, beanshell

Following are the steps that I need to peform

1. Make http request call to a sevice which returns a json that has many urls.
2. Extract all the urls using regular expression extractor
3. Make http request call to all the exctracted urls asynchronously.

Is there a way we can achieve this? I tried parallel controller but, if I am not wrong, it requires all the request to be mentioned as its child sampler. I don't want to write each and every request manually. Is there a way we can change urls dynamically after running the test plan?

Comment: You can check BeanShell for doing pre and post processing [specially executing scripts i.e. in you case parsing json etc.] https://dzone.com/articles/beanshell-processor-in-jmeter and https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-beanshell-jmeters-favorite-built-component

Comment: A related post is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512365/jmeter-run-a-python-script-before-calling-each-http-request-sampler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's better to use [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) if the server returns URLs in JSON format
2. Once you have the URLs in form of JMeter Variables like:

   ```
   url_1=http://example.com
   url_2=http://example.org
   ........
   ........
   url_matchNr=X
   ```

   - add [Parallel Sampler](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-sampler) to your Test Plan
   - add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the Parallel Sampler
   - Put the following code into "Script" area:

     ```
      1.upto(vars.get('url_matchNr') as int, { index ->
          sampler.addURL(vars.get('url_' + index))
      })
     ```